# How do I can I get data from model functions to appear in Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

How can I get data for `get_num_states` to appear as a field, showing number of states a country has, in Django Admin for each record I have of a country? I know that `get_num_states` seems to be working as I am able to display info from the function in html templates. However I currently don't see it displaying in Django Admin.

```
class Country(models.Model):
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def get_num_states(self):
        return State.objects.filter(country=self.id).count()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country_name

class State(models.Model):
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Where do you expect to display this `get_num_states()` function value in your Django Admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to display the result in *list page*,

```
class CountryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'country_name', 'states_count')

    def states_count(self, instance):
        return instance.get_num_states()


admin.site.register(Country, CountryAdmin)
```

---

#### Update-1

to get the method value in detail/change view, you have to create a model form and link the same in django admin

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    states_count = forms.IntegerField(disabled=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = ('country_name', 'states_count')

    def get_initial_for_field(self, field, field_name):
        if field_name == 'rating':
            if self.instance:
                return self.instance.get_num_states()
            return None
        return super().get_initial_for_field(field, field_name)


class CountryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm


admin.site.register(Country, CountryAdmin)
```

Comment: This works great for displaying it on list page. How can I display it on each individual country record, in django admin?

Comment: I mean how to display on individual country record page